# Samsung Galaxy Note 2 wont charge while on and battery is discharging

Tags: battery, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2

So after reformatting my phone, resetting to defaults, nothing has seem to work.
I even took it to my cell provider to see the tech, they didn't do anything.
Whats weird is that it had 20% and so i took the battery out of the phone and stuck it back in, right when it turned on says 55%, strange right? Does anyone know WTF to do I really want to chuck this phone away, nothing but problems :(

Comment: That is indeed strange. I wonder if your battery itself is damaged or faulty. Did the tech test to see if it worked with a different battery?

Comment: Thats what i thought as well. He did a battery test and he said the battery is fine. I'm not sure if he tried with another battery, i don't think so. Hmm, I am going to go back and see if he can do another battery. I hope so.